How to convert more than one array(different size) per row to columns
Sample query with data:
with `mydata.data` as (
  select [1] as ArrayA, [1,2,3] ArrayB, 'AA' columnString1, 'ABA' columnString2
  union all 
  select [6,3,3], [5,6,7,4] ,'AA','ABC',
)
select * 
from (
  select ArrayA, ArrayB,columnString1, columnString2, offset
  from `mydata.data`, 
  unnest(ArrayA) ArrayA with offset
  join unnest(ArrayB) ArrayB with offset
  using (offset)
)
pivot (ANY_VALUE(ArrayA) ArrayA, ANY_VALUE(ArrayB) ArrayB for offset in (0, 1, 2, 3))


as the result we get:



columnString1
columnString2
ArrayA_0
ArrayB_0
ArrayA_1
ArrayB_1
ArrayA_2
ArrayB_2
ArrayA_3
ArrayB_3




AA
ABA
1
1
null
null
null
null
null
null


AA
ABC
6
5
3
6
3
7
null
null



my expected result would be:



columnString1
columnString2
ArrayA_0
ArrayB_0
ArrayA_1
ArrayB_1
ArrayA_2
ArrayB_2
ArrayA_3
ArrayB_3




AA
ABA
1
1
null
2
null
3
null
null


AA
ABC
6
5
3
6
3
7
null
4




So far I have managed to create such a solution:
with `mydata.data` as (
  select [1] as ArrayA, [1,2,3] ArrayB, 'AA' columnString1, 'ABA' columnString2
  union all 
  select [6,3,3], [5,6,7,4] ,'AA','ABC',
)
SELECT A.*, B.* EXCEPT(columnString1,columnString2) FROM 
(select * 
from (
  select ArrayA,columnString1, columnString2, offset
  from `mydata.data`, 
  unnest(ArrayA) ArrayA with offset
) 
pivot (ANY_VALUE(ArrayA) ArrayA for offset in (0, 1, 2, 3))) A JOIN
(select * 
from (
  select ArrayB,columnString1, columnString2, offset
  from `mydata.data`, 
  unnest(ArrayB) ArrayB with offset
)
pivot (ANY_VALUE(ArrayB) ArrayB for offset in (0, 1, 2, 3))) B ON A.columnString1 = B.columnString1 AND A.columnString2 = B.columnString2


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
